# find: Only allow one specific subdirectory

Tags: find

I have the following folder structure

```
| subdirectoy1
| |
| |_ file1.jpg
| |_ file2.jpg
| |_ ...
|
| subdirectory2
| |
| |_ file11.jpg
| |_ file12.jpg
| |_ ...
|
| ...
|
|_ file21.jpg
|_ file22.jpg
|_ ...
```

As you can see, there are some files at the root level of that folder and various subdirectories (more than the two in my tree here) with each of them containing more images.

My idea is now, that I want to *find* both the root level images and the images in subdirectory1, but **not** those in the other directories.

Well, I could go the easy way and just exclude the other directories one by one

```
find . -type f -not -path "*subdirectory2*" -exec ...
```

but I want this line to be more adaptable for cases when the other folders aren't named *subdirectory2* and so on.

Or in other words: Is there a way to say

```
find . -maxdepth 1 ...
```

but with the exception of one specific subdirectory below that boundry?

Comment: Does it really have to be a single `find`? Looks like running `find` twice should solve that.

Comment: -not is not supported by find...never use it

Answer (score 4):

You can prune directories which aren’t `subdirectory1`:

```
find . ! \( -name . -o -name subdirectory1 \) -prune -type f
```

You can add whatever you want to do with the files after `-type f`.

This works as follows:

- Starting in the current directory

  - prune anything which doesn’t match `.` or `subdirectory1` (this will ignore any other directory)
  - keep only regular files

This will find all files in the current directory and in `subdirectory1` (without descending into `subdirectory1`’s sub-directories).